# Is it safe to use 4-digit PIN as MacOS password like in Windows 10?

Tags: macos, security

On Windows 10 desktop I can set 4-digit pin to log in (after I've logged in with Microsoft Account) and it's relatively safe. So it's quick to type in the PIN throughout the work day.

I wonder if it's just as secure to set a 4-digit pin on macOS?

Comment: To clarify - you wish to set your user account passphrase to a 4 digit value?

Answer (score 4):

No it is not as secure. This is because the PIN (password on macOS) is entered at startup/login and without any further passwords gives access to iCloud and potentially multiple other cloud services, as well as everything on the Mac including all your email messages.

The only thing still protected would be *managing* your iCloud account which will require your iCloud password. Any passwords (e.g. those to web sites) you (or Safari) have stored in your Keychain are fully usable.

You must follow your own risk assessment, but if it were me I would not even consider what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 2):

No way is a 4 digit password secure for a computer log in.

- https://support.apple.com/en-bw/guide/mac-help/flvlt003/mac

It violates the first recommendation to [Choose a password with eight characters or more and a mix of different character types](https://support.apple.com/en-bw/guide/mac-help/mchlp1088/mac)

Once you’ve chosen a secure password for sign in, [review the other passwords you may need to consider securing and how they relate on macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-bw/guide/mac-help/mchlp2555/mac).

For quick access, perhaps a physical token or [Apple hardware with biometric assistance](https://support.apple.com/en-bw/guide/mac-help/mchl16fbf90a/mac) will let you secure your Mac and unlock quickly?

- https://www.yubico.com/products/